# What is max[$XY + YZ + ZX$] if $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 =1$?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

For real $X,Y,Z$, how to find the maximum of $XY+YZ+ZX$ subjected to condition $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 =1$? I am aware of the fact that for a single variable function $f(x)$, one would simply find the critical points and apply the second derivative test. But how can one handle this multiparameter problem?

Comment: What is $(X + Y + Z)^2$ on the sphere $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 1$?

Comment: Do you understand why the second derivative test works? Do you think you can see a generalisation involving partial derivatives?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers work well here.

Comment: Consider applying the Cauchy inequality. $(xy+yz+zx)^2\leq (x^2+y^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2+x^2)$. So the max value is $1$, when $x=y=z$.

Comment: Or the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Answer (score 5):

Who needs derivatives?

$1-(xy+xz+yz)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(xy+xz+yz)$

$=(\frac12x^2-xy+\frac12y^2)+(\frac12x^2-xz+\frac12z^2)+(\frac12y^2-yz+\frac12z^2)$

$=\frac12(x-y)^2+\frac12(x-z)^2+\frac12(y-z)^2\ge0.$

Thus $xy+xz+yz\le1$, and since equality is met by rendering $x=y=z=\sqrt{\frac13}$, this upper bound of $1$ represents the true maximum.

This problem is homogeneous, so for any nonnegative $c$ we find that if $x^2+y^2+z^2=c$ then the maximum of $xy+xz+yz$ will also be $c$.